# Exporting sounds as WAV files

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I never worked too much with sounds in Mma.

I have

```
t = Sound[List["Violin",SoundNote[-6]]]
```

How could I Export `t` as a .WAV file?

When I try the obvious

```
Export["c:\\test.wav",t]
```

I get

[image]

[In this old thread](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/mathematica/12507/Exporting-Sound#fittsn93l1smcvnetnet) Szabolcs said that it can't be done. Perhaps things have improved since 2007!

Comment: You specifically mean `MIDI -> WAV`, right? I can export arbitrary sound forms as WAV.

Comment: @yoda I only need to export my `t` thingy in the example above (well, not really, but all others are very much like it). I am not educated in sound formats, so perhaps that means MIDI->WAV, but I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it still can't be done. Mathematica supports creating and modifying [MIDI](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MIDI.html) objects, but leaves the sound generation from the midi to the underlying operating system. For now, you'll have to export to midi then use the midi interface on your system or an online service to convert to a sampled sound format.

For example (from the documentation)

```
t = Sound[SoundNote[DeleteCases[3 Range[31] Reverse[#], 0] - 48, .1] & /@ 
   Transpose[CellularAutomaton[90, {{1}, 0}, 30]]]
Export["test.mid", t]
```

Uploaded to http://free-midi-converter.com/Midi/Create gives the [link](http://free-midi-converter.com/Midi/Details/5740).

It can also be converted with [TiMidity](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/) which is available on all major operating systems with the command (assuming you've run the above)

```
Run["timidity test.mid -Ow -o test.wav"]
```

which can be imported back into Mathematica using `Import["test.wav"]`.

This conversion can be automated if need be...

---

Apparently [VLC can also convert midi to wav](https://superuser.com/questions/230831/command-line-midi-to-wav-converter), which might be an easier option for some propriety operating systems!  See also the options given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/145424/how-to-convert-from-midi-to-wav).

Comment: Thanks Simon! Tried VLC ... not working, tried Audacity, can't follow instructions. Timidity is next. Calculating ClebschGordan coeffs was easier.

Comment: @belisarius, I also use online converters for this, as Simon suggested.  Why not try one?  Last time I tried, setting up Timidity on Windows was a pain (but that was years ago)

Comment: @Szabolcs I'll try anyway and then report my adventure here. Thanks a lot for sharing your experience!

Comment: @belisarius: How are your adventures treating you?

Comment: @Simon Solved it quick and dirty with the online service. Next week I'll try Timidity.

Comment: @belisarius: Made with timidity?

Comment: @Simon Nope. I have some issue with the sound drivers and Timidity isn't working. BTW Look at this http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/markov-chain-beatbox-generator/3764#3764

Comment: @belisarius: Even if timidity is not talking to your sound card, it might still be able to convert midi to wav... (btw, is there a stack exchange site that you're not active on? :) )