# Superposing music tracks in Mathematica & MIDI pedal events

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, midi

All of the following refers to music/MIDI (`SoundNote` objects), not sampled sounds.

Unfortunately Mathematica doesn't seem to be able to import MIDI.  I'm trying to make a simple MIDI importer based on [MIDI <-> CSV](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/) for single-instrument files (focused on piano).

**What is the simplest way to superpose two `Sound` objects in Mathematica?**

`Show` concatenates them, it doesn't superpose.

A not-too simple approach is to disassemble the `Sound` into `SoundNote`s, convert each `SoundNote`s time specification into `{Tstart, Tend}` format, and assemble these into a new sound.  Is there a simple way?

A second question:

**Is there a simple way to handle pedal events in Mathematica**, while still using the internal sound representation and MIDI player, and not playing the MIDI through some other means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Superposition

In order to be able to superimpose two `Sound` objects, there ought to be a common time origin. A simple `SoundNote` object has its own time origin and hence using `Sound` on a list of these will only concatenate them and plays them in serial. You will have to use absolute times for each in order to superimpose them. This way, you can compose MIDI music with multiple instruments playing at the same time.

Here's a short example (not polished) of superimposing. The bass notes are played by a Piano and the treble notes are played by a Clarinet.

```
tempo = 110;
eighthNoteDuration = 60/tempo/2;

trebleNotes = {"E5", "D#5", "E5", "D#5", "E5", "B", "D5", "C5", "A", 
   None, "C", "E", "A", "B", None, "E", "G#", "B", "C5", None, "E", 
   "E5", "D#5", "E5", "D#5", "E5", "B", "D5", "C5", "A", None, "C", 
   "E", "A", "B", None, "E", "C5", "B", "A"};
trebleNoteDurations = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 4} eighthNoteDuration;
trebleTimings = 
  Partition[
   Accumulate@Flatten@Transpose@{ConstantArray[0, Length@#], #} &@
    trebleNoteDurations, 2];

bassNotes = {None, None, "A2", "E3", "A3", None, None, "E3", "G#3", 
   "B3", None, None, "A2", "E3", "A3", None, None, None, "A2", "E3", 
   "A3", None, None, "E3", "G#3", "B3", None, None, "A2", "E3", "A3", 
   None};
bassNoteDurations = {2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1} eighthNoteDuration;
bassTimings = 
  Partition[
   Accumulate@Flatten@Transpose@{ConstantArray[0, Length@#], #} &@
    bassNoteDurations, 2];

Sound[Join[
  SoundNote[#1, #2, 
     "Piano"] & @@@ ({bassNotes, bassTimings}\[Transpose]), 
  SoundNote[#1, #2, 
     "Clarinet"] & @@@ ({trebleNotes, trebleTimings}\[Transpose])]]
```

#### 2. Pedal effects

As for your second question, I don't think you can reproduce pedal effects using MIDI. The MIDI format is pretty simple and does not actually transmit any sound. All the information it carries is

1. The note being played (pitch)
2. The duration of the note (tempo)
3. Trigger events to start and stop the note

The instrument you choose to reproduce the sound is entirely dependent on your system and may reproduce differently on different systems. Now if you want to reproduce a pedal effect, you will have to write a function to break it up into individual MIDI events that closely resemble the actual effect of the pedal.

For example, you could modify `SoundNote` or create a new function that, when passed an option `Sustain -> t`, prolongs the note for `t` seconds. You can make this more realistic and chop up the `t` seconds into smaller segments, with `SoundVolume -> v` as an additional option and `v` decreasing linearly/logarithmically with each segment.

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking of something similar, it seems there's no easier way then.  Regarding the pedal, it is in fact part of MIDI.  In the CSV representation, pressing or releasing the pedal appears as `Control_c, 0, 64, 127`, which means set the value of controller 64 to 127 (press pedal) or to 0 (release pedal).  Of course it is up to the MIDI instrument used if it will do something with this event or not, but generally any piano-style instrument should respond to it.

Comment: I think I'm going to use my own MIDI representation in Mathematica, and write a converter to both `Sound` objects and MIDI files.  With `Sound` objects one could emulate the sustain pedal by extending every note until the pedal is released.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that MIDI can transmit pedalling information. It transmits it through CC #64, I just don't know how are you going to implement this on Mathematica. [Source](http://www.amazon.com/Acoustic-MIDI-Orchestration-Contemporary-Composer/dp/0240520211), Also, yoda's comment on MIDI is VERY incomplete - yoda, are you refering to the MIDI protocol itself or to MIDI on Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

As to your second question:

Earlier I [reported](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6676852&tstart=0) on Mathematica's ability to connect to a Nintendo Wiimote and Balanceboard, using the programs [GlovePie](https://web.archive.org/web/20180331012620/http://glovepie.org:80/glovepie.php) and PPJoy, a virtual joystick driver that lets Mathematica interface with your device by simulating a joystick (which MMA can read using `ControllerState` or `ControllerInformation`). As far as I know GlovePie also supports MIDI. You might give it a try.

Comment: The Mac version of Mathematica supports MIDI devices natively via the ControllerState[] function. There's no need for any virtual joystick driver.

Comment: @ragfield I guess Windows doesn't, right?  I get "No controller devices detected" from `ControllerInformation[]` when I connect a piano to the computer.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a way to output sound while also taking into account the effect of the sustain pedal (I'm only interested in piano-style instruments now), but this doesn't seem to be possible in Mathematica.  What GlovePie lets me do is control Mathematica using an external MIDI keyboard (possibly also with the pedal).

Comment: @szabolcs Correct, the built-in MIDI support in ControllerState is Mac-only.

Comment: @szabolcs I presume timing may be a problem here. The ear is very sensitive to delays in the sound production. That's why musicians always use ASIO drivers. Routing MIDI data through two programs before feeding it to Mathematica (which also doesn't guarantee real-time processing) might be far from optimal in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine, or superimpose, sound waves using convolution, as shown by the Mathematica code on this page:

http://www.copperthoughts.com/projects/convolution/

Comment: The OP has clearly stated that he's talking about MIDI objects and not sampled sound. You can't convolve a MIDI object with anything...

Comment: @yoda, but a MIDI object is a representation of sound, in some sense. So, along with a conversion to sound, convolution could be effective. That just makes his solution incomplete.

Comment: @rcollyer A MIDI object is a set of instructions. How the output is rendered depends on the system. In theory, you can labour to convert it into a sampled sound, convolve and then back to a set of MIDI instructions (if the result is even representable by MIDI). But MIDI files are not all that easy to manipulate, sample and export, as I found out when trying to come up with a solution to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7592596/).